# data binding of a property not properly working in wpf. Binding expression path error

Tags: c#, wpf

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LabelWidth' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-842352752)'. BindingExpression:Path=LabelWidth; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-842352752); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
I am getting this error. I do not know why I am having this error. Normally this error occurs because of wrong DataContext.

```
 public class SignalBaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public ulong Counter { get; set; }
     public double MinimumLabelWidth { get; set; }
            public double MinimumMargin { get; set; }
            public ulong NumberOfBoxes { get; set; }
     private double labelWidth;

            public double LabelWidth
            {
                get { return labelWidth; }
                set
                {
                    labelWidth = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LabelWidth");
                }

            }


            private double myMargin;

            public double MyMargin
            {
                get { return myMargin; }
                set
                {
                    myMargin = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyMargin");
                }
            }


         public void AddLabels(double lbs)
                {
                    TimeAxis.Clear();

                      Counter = 0;
                    MinimumMargin = 3;
                    MinimumLabelWidth = 27;

                    for (double i = 0; i < (ulong)lbs; i++) 
                    {
                        TimeAxis.Add(Counter.ToString()); 
                        var tp = i;
                        var chachu = (TimeAxis[TimeAxis.Count-1].Length);
                        var boxes = (chachu / 4.0);

                        NumberOfBoxes = (ulong)Math.Ceiling(boxes);
                        Counter += (SampleStepSize * NumberOfBoxes) ;
                            if (NumberOfBoxes > 1)
                            {
                                i += (NumberOfBoxes - 1);



                            }

                        LabelWidth = (NumberOfBoxes * MinimumLabelWidth);

                        MyMargin = (MinimumMargin * NumberOfBoxes);



                    }
                    if (CanvasWidth > Convert.ToUInt64(TimeAxis.LastOrDefault()))
                    {
                        TimeAxis.Add(Counter.ToString());
                    }

                }

}
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeAxis}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="horizontalLabels" Orientation="Horizontal"  />

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <TextBlock     Text="{Binding}" 
                                           Width="{Binding LabelWidth}"   Background="Red" Height="30"  FontSize="12"
                            Margin="{Binding MyMargin, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=marginConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange}">

                            </TextBlock>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>


public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new Thickness(0, 0, System.Convert.ToDouble(value), 0);
        }
```

Comment: The binding context of your `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate` is the current `TimeAxis` item. This item is just a string and a string does not contain a property `LabelWidth`. You need to reference the original binding context

Comment: `Width="{Binding DataContext.LabelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`

Comment: @thank you to both of you. I was thinking TextBlock will get the same datacontext which timeaxis is having i.e main datacontext. Now my concept is clear. thanks.